# How to divide a length-valued macro by a dimensionless-valued macro?

Tags: pstricks, calculations

I have attempted to do as follows, but it does not work.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\psset
{
    xunit=\dimexpr1cm/\psPi\relax,
    yunit=1cm
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,-1)(\psPi,1)
    \psplot[plotpoints=300,algebraic]{0}{\psPi}{sin(2*x)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

How to divide a length-valued macro by a dimensionless-valued macro?

Comment: I just noticed, this issue will disappear if I use an integer dimensionless value. But I need 3.141592654 rather than 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do that directly. In TeX, a length can be only divided by integers. eTeX's `\dimexpr` and `\numexpr` can do nothing but what Knuth TeX's primitives can do. Thus the calculation 1cm/3.14 is not supported.

There is a trick to do this kind of calculation in TeX:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\def\psPi{3.1415926}
\newcount\tmpcntA
\newdimen\tmpdimA
\newcount\tmpcntB
\newdimen\tmpdimB

\begin{document}

\tmpdimA=2cm
\tmpcntA=\tmpdimA % 3729359, in sp
\tmpdimB=\psPi pt
\tmpcntB=\tmpdimB % 205887, in sp
\divide\tmpcntA by \tmpcntB % 3729359 / 205887 = 2cm / 3.1416926pt
\tmpdimA=\tmpcntA pt % 2cm / 3.1415926pt * 1pt
                     % = 2cm / 3.1415926

\the\tmpdimA % 2cm/3.1415926 = 18.0pt

\end{document}
```

But it's not precise because of truncation. The approch cannot be used in many situations.

---

The better way is to use other method to do the calculation: `fp` package, `pgf`'s math engine, raw PostScript calculation, etc.

I'm not very familar with PSTricks, here is the `pst-fp` solution:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\pstFPdiv\result{2}{\psPi} % pst-fp is used

\psset
{
  xunit=\result cm, % 0.636619773... cm
  yunit=1cm
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,-1)(\psPi,1)
  \psplot[plotpoints=300,algebraic]{0}{\psPi}{sin(2*x)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `@`Leo:In the ps-bundle exist a package called `pst-fp`. So you don't need a package like `fp`. The package `pst-fp` defines the command `\pstFPdiv` which is equivalent to `\FPdiv`.

Comment: @Marco: Thank you. I knew `pst-fp`, but I thought it has only `\FPadd` and `\FPminus` (in fact it also has multiply and divide, but no more).  And `pst-fp` is just a copy of `fp`.

Comment: '@Leo: Of course: In fact you don't need any further packages :-) because `pst-fp` is loaded automatically. I didn`t math the two packages ;-)